# Reference External File In Excel Using The Current Week Number

Tags: excel

I am trying to pull a number from an external excel file that sits in a sub folder where my main file is stored.
The formula I am using is

```
='"K:\Ops Report\Weekly Ops\2018\Week  "&INT((TODAY()-(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))))/7)&"\Weekly Control\Data Control\Weekly Control\Data Control\"&[Template.xlsx]Membership'!$B$4
```

This throws a #REF! Error, and changes the formula to

```
='"K:\Ops Report\Weekly Ops\2018\Week  "&INT((TODAY()-(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))))/7)&"\Weekly Control\Data Control\Weekly Control\Data Control\["&[Template.xlsx]Membership]"&[Template.xlsx]Membership'!$B$4
```

I need this formula to update every week when the report is being created so I can't simply reference the file. I am also aware that I will have to change the year section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it this way with closed workbook. Try this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/lzqhzexSvH4/dQAPVlM3RKwJ

IF the target workbook is open, then you can use `INDIRECT()`.

`=INDIRECT("'K:\Ops Report\Weekly Ops\2018\Week  "&INT((TODAY()-(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))))/7)&"\Weekly Control\Data Control\Weekly Control\Data Control\[Template.xlsx]Membership'!$B$4")`

See more here: https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-workbook-reference

All in all, you can use VBA to perform this action with closed workbooks.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that I have some syntax error as I think my formula is working somewhat. The #Ref! indicates that it is looking for something doesn't it? I would rather not have the second workbook open if possible, and I don't want to use VBA as this is actually to accommodate a RPA process

Comment: The #REF! error shows when a formula refers to a cell that’s not valid - here referring to a closed external workbook is not valid.

Comment: I don't understand? If I save the referenced workbook to a general location and reference it directly it works? The only difference is I don't want to do that, I want it to pull the relevant file for the relevant week. I also think that the fact it changes my formula afterwards means there is some slight bug in it?

Comment: Yes, then it should work. The problem is you are trying to get value by reference to a workbook provided in a string - but that is not possible, unless you use `INDIRECT()` function. But this function requires targeted workbook to be open.

Comment: But you said previously the #Ref error was to do with a closed workbook. The fact that I am getting that error, does that not mean the week number is working bu that something is slightly wrong with how I reference the cell?

Comment: I was mistaken then. This is a reference: `'C:/[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'A1`. This is a string not a reference, hence the error: `"'C:/"&STH&"[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'A1"`

Comment: Would you know how to amend my calculation?

Comment: I updated `INDIRECT()` formula in answer. But remember - target workbook must be opened.